dotnet doesn't trust self-sign certificate when deployed on kubernetes
I have two services deployed in kubernetes
Flow Application
When start service api connect to Service identity.

Service identity


Attach self-sing certificate to PATH:/https/my-certificate.pfx
Listen HTTPS Port 443


Service api


Attach self-sing certificate to PATH:/etc/ssl/certs/my-certificate.crt (Convert from 'my-certificate.pfx')
Attach CA certificate to PATH:/etc/ssl/certs/my-CA-certificate.crt
Run command : update-ca-certificates
enter image description here

But service api error, because it's not trusted.

[04:23:21 INF] Start processing HTTP request GET https://idp.egp-client/.well-known/openid-configuration <s:System.Net.Http.Httpclient.Default.LogicalHandler>
[04:23:21 INF] Send ing HTTPrequest GEThttps://idp.egp-client/.well-know/openid-configuration s :System.Net.Http.Httpclient.Default.clienthandler>
Unhandled exception. System.Net.Http.HttpRequestExcept ion: The ssL connection could not be established, see inner exception.


->System. Secur ity. Authent icat ion.Authent icat ionExcept ion: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: NotSignaturevalid, UntrustedRoot
at System.Net.Security.Sslstream.SendAuthResetS ignal(ReadOnlySpan1 alert, ExceptionDispatchInfoexception)
at System.Net .security.sslstream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthent icat ionopt inssslAuthent icat ionopt ions

CA-Certificate

cert ificate:
signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Issuer: C = TH, ST = Some-State, 0 = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
Validity
Not Before: Apr 6 07:31:30 2024 GMT
Not After : Apr 6 07:31:30 2025 GMT
Subject: C = TH, ST = Some-State, 0 = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
Subject Public Key Info:
Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublickey

Certifiacte

Certificate:
Signature Algorithm: ecdsa-with-SHA256
Issuer: C = TH, ST = Some-State, 0 = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
validity
Not Before: Apr 6 07:51:25 2024 GMT
Not After : Apr 6 07:51:25 2025 GMT
subject: C = TH, ST = Some-State, 0 = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
Subject Public Key Info:
Public Key Algorithm: id-ecpublickey
Public-Key: (256 bit)

.pfx
certificate bag
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: F7 33 26 5D 49 50 36 C2 4A C8 47 DC 6A 65 AD D9 70 BD F5 OU
subject=c = TH, ST = Some-State, 0 = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
issuer=c = TH, ST = Some-State, O = Internet Widgits Pty Ltd, CN = idp.egp-client
I want to the service api to trust certificate service identity or more solution, but service uses HTTPS.
